# file [rospack find turtlebot_navigation/nav_rviz.vcg] does not exist

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having trouble with the navigation tutorial.  Map is correctly saved but can not be brought up in rviz.  Opening up rviz shows a black map (when it should be grey?).  There is a "Global Status Error: Target Frame - For frame [/kinect_rgb_frame]: Frame [/kinect_rgb_frame] does not exist"

When I quit rviz I notice the following error:

"File [rospack find turtlebot_navigation/nav_rviz.vcg] does not exist"

Does that mean that rviz was not initialized properly with the map data?

Not sure if this is related but I am using "roscore" to bringup the bot instead of the "sudo service turtlebot start"

Thanks for the help in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11885/file-%5Brospack-find-turtlebot_navigation/nav_rviz.vcg%5D-does-not-exist/) by [hxorn00b](https://answers.ros.org/users/1354/hxorn00b/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error:

```
"File [rospack find turtlebot_navigation/nav_rviz.vcg] does not exist"
```

means that it could not find the vcg file in the turtlebot_navigation folder. It does not mean it could not load your map. All the vcg file does it help you configure your rviz environment. The file should be located in the turtlebot_navigation package. If not, try updating your software.

The error:

```
"Global Status Error: Target Frame - For frame [/kinect_rgb_frame]: Frame [/kinect_rgb_frame] does not exist"
```

means that the frame you are trying to view does not exist. Most likely your fixed frame in rviz is set to kinect_rgb_frame, to get rid of this error click on the fixed frame box and select a different frame from the list like base link. For an overview of how rviz works see here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/UserGuide.

Most likely the reason your map is not being displayed is because the map display module is not loaded. If you click on the add button at the right bottom of the rviz window, then select map and select ok. Once you have added the map module you must select the topic to listen to for the map, click on the topic field and select the map topic and the map should appear.

On a side note, you need to use more than roscore to bring up TurtleBot. sudo service turtlebot start actually just launches minimal.launch in turtlebot_bringup.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1